# Semantic understanding of unit and integration tests in Axon-based applications

Tags: java, spring-boot, domain-driven-design, axon

As we know Axon has its own tools to implement tests. In documentation we can see example with flights like:

```
FixtureConfiguration<Flight> fixture = new AggregateTestFixture<>(Flight.class);

@Test
void test() {
    fixture.given(/* historical events */)
        .when(new RegisterArrivalTimeCommand(flightId, newArrivalTime))
        .expectEventsMatching(
            Matchers.exactSequenceOf(
                Matchers.messageWithPayload(
                    Matchers.matches(payload -> {
                        // compare payload with expectations
                    })
                )
            )
        );
}
```

So, here we see how Axon's aggregate mock(fixture) is created and we see test with assertion(use of matchers). Previously I didn't work in project which had domain driven design, but in other types of projects we have Junit(allows use to write isolated unit-tests using Java) and tools for integration testing(Rest-assured, Cucumber), which allow us to test whole feature/functionality.

And looking on code in example appeared question - Axon tests can be divided in these 2 groups(unit, integration)? Which tests can be called unit? Those, where we send just one command and check all events which apear after it? Or all the tests will be integrational, when we can write one test on concrete flow with commands and events?

Comment: I would encourage you to raise this very interesting question in the forum: https://discuss.axoniq.io/.  There is no true/false correct answer but it is interesting to think about how to test.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to understand where you should place the `AggregateTestFixture` on the scope of Unit-to-Integration tests? Or is it something else you're trying to define here? Right now I feel I can only make assumptions on your last couple of questions instead of fully comprehending what you're trying to achieve.